# Proof in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, proof-verification

May you help me with this problem?

This is just a draft... I do not see how to continue...

***Construct a proof for the following arguments***

Premise 1:

[image: Graph 1]

Premise 2:

[image: Graph 2]

Premise 3:

[image: Graph 3]

Premise 4:

[image: Graph 4]

Premise 5:

[image: Graph 5]

Conclusion:

[image: Graph Conclusion]

Sentence number 6 (using premise number 1):

(x) [Qx implies Px and [(Rx iff Tx)]]

Sentence number 7 (using conclusion):

Let assume Qx (Conditional Proof Assumption-CPA)

Sentence number 8 (using sentences 7 and 6, modus ponens) :

Px and (Rx iff Tx)

Sentence number 9 (simplification 9):

Px

Sentence number 10 (simplification 9):

(Rx iff Tx)

Sentence number 11 (using 2):

not Ax or Bx or not Sx

Sentence number 12 (using 3):

not Ax or Sx

Sentence number 13 (using 4):

Qx implies (Px or Tx)

Sentence number 14 (using 13):

Px or Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

From 1) : $\forall x [Qx \to (Px \to \lnot (Rx \equiv Tx))]$.

Rewriting the premises :

From 1) : $Qx \to (Px \to \lnot (Rx \equiv Tx))$

From 2) : $Px \equiv [(Sx \land Ax) \to Bx]$

From 3) : $Ax \to Sx$

From 4) : $Qx \to (Px \lor Tx)$

From 5) $(Px \equiv Rx) \to Ax$

> a) $Qx$ --- assumed fro Conditional Proof

b) $Px \lor Tx$ --- from 4) by *modus ponens*.

Proof by cases :

> b-1) $Tx$ then : $Tx \lor Bx$ and we are done;

and :

> b-2) $Px$ then by 1) and 2) : $\lnot (Rx \equiv Tx)$, by *mp* twice.

We have to "unpack" $\equiv$ and using De Morgan we get :

c) $\lnot (Rx \to Tx) \lor \lnot (Tx \to Rx)$ and thus by cases again :

> c-1) $Tx \land \lnot Rx$

and by simplification : $Tx$ that gives again : $Tx \lor Bx$ as above;

and :

> c-2) $Rx \land \lnot Tx$;

we simplify it to $Rx$ and thus : $Px \to Rx$ [by the *tautology* : $r \to (p \to r)$].

We are in the sub-proof from b-2) : $Px$ and as above : $Rx \to Px$.

Thus we have : $P \equiv Rx$ and from 5) we get : $Ax$ and then : $Sx$ from 3).

From 2) [we still have assumption $Px$] we get : $Bx$ and thus : $Tx \lor Bx$ again.

Up to now, we have derived : $(Tx \lor Bx)$ in all cases of the two nested proofs by cases and thus we may conclude with : $(Tx \lor Bx)$ closing the sub-proofs.

Thus, we have a derivation of :

> $\{ \text {premises 1-5} \} \cup Qx \vdash (Tx \lor Bx)$;

we have to use CP followed by generalization to derive :

> > $\{ \text {premises 1-5} \} \vdash \forall x [Qx \to (Tx \lor Bx)]$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I was 10 hours working on this problem and I did not see the idea that you found to unpack Rx iff Tx connected with DeMorgan's law and proof by cases. Your solution has taught me a lot! Thank you so much! You are a genius!

Comment: I also learned a lot in the way that you wrote your proof! You did a great job! Thank you again!

Comment: I have only one doubt about your brilliant proof. How did you get Px iff Rx? I got Px implies Rx, but then you used a tautology. In my perspective that tautology shows Rx implies (Px implies Rx), that is not the same than Rx implies Px, or am I wrong? I was thinking if we can use the fact that Px and Rx are always true to affirm that Px iff Rx is also true, but I am not sure if I am cheating. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Beginner - we have both. With assumption $Rx$ and taut $Rx \to (Px \to Rx)$ we detach $(Px \to Rx)$ and with assumption $Px$ (still active) and taut $Px \to (Rx \to Px)$ we detach $(Rx \to Px)$.

Comment: Thank you Mauro for being in touch! I believe that as we have Px, we can  get (not Rx or Px), that is equivalent to Rx impies Px, and as we have Rx can get (not Px or Rx) that is equivalent to Px implies Rx. Later we can join both to get Px iff Rx. That is what you are using, correct? Thank you for your help! I appreciate a lot your time and teachings!